# Direct link to a specifc tab in a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to redirect a page to specific `TAB link`. For example

```
    <a href="#google">google</a> 
      <a href="#facebook">facebook</a> 

<div class="tab containt">
    <div id="google">
        <p>some text some text some text some text</p>
    </div>

    <div id="facebook">
        <p>some text some text some text some text</p>
    </div>
</div
```

Is there any possibility to redirect to a specific tab?

http://example.com/#facebook

http://example.com/#facebook by placing this url in address bar. Its should directly open the facebook tab

Comment: It really depends... what kind of programming language are you using? Client sided scripts only (HTML, JS etc)? Or also server sided scripts? Personally, I always use PHP, and for this situation, I would use a get variable, i.e. `example.com/?tab=facebook`  and then have a little script make `facebook` the visible tab (by hiding the google tab with `display: none;`) when this `$_GET` variable is set to `facebook`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982594/how-do-i-preserve-uri-fragment-in-safari-upon-redirect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35863758/4763793

Answer (score 0):

Add a class `moveTo` to the link to be clicked.

**HTML**

```
<a class="moveTo" href="#google">google</a><br/>
<a class="moveTo" href="#facebook">facebook</a><br/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".moveTo").click(function(){
        var elemId = $(this).attr('href')
        $(elemId).find('a:first').click();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/xFW8t/868/)

Answer (score 0):

Without more requirements, you can use [`:target`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp) selector as **pure CSS solution**.

> URLs with an # followed by an anchor name, link to a certain element within a document. The element being linked to is the target element.

> The :target selector can be used to style the current active target element.

```css
.tab > div {
  display:none;  
}

.tab > div:target {
  display:block;  
}
```

```html
<a href="#google">google</a> 
<a href="#facebook">facebook</a> 

<div class="tab containt">
  <div id="google">
    <p>some text some text some text some text - google</p>
  </div>
  <div id="facebook">
    <p>some text some text some text some text - facebook</p>
  </div>
</div>
```